Which hole should I use to mount a curtain rod with only one anchor?
I am installing a curtain/drapery rod in a bedroom. I can't directly affix the rod to a stud.
The rod system has a small wall bracket that you attach to the wall surface and then slip the rod end over. The height of the bracket is maybe 1.5 inches in total height, and the rod manufacturer has provided 2 screws and 2 cheap plastic drywall anchors for each bracket.
----------
----------  bracket schematic - oo are the holes for each screw. 
--- oo ---
--- oo ---
----------  } this gap/space is approx. 1/4 to 1/2 inch
----------  }
--- oo ---
--- oo ---
----------
----------

I want to secure the bracket to the wall with toggle bolts instead. The problem is that there isn't enough space to install two toggle bolts that close to each other - the radius of the two holes needed to install two toggles to connect to the bracket would intersect each other (another issue is that the toggles behind the wall may intersect with each other).
I think one toggle bolt will have far better holding capacity than 2 plastic drywall plugs, but I'm wondering which hole will be better to use, the top or the bottom on the bracket - the top hole would seem to be subject to more of the tension of the weight of the curtains, so I think I'd want it secured on the top hole. In contrast, if you secure it by the bottom bracket, the top pulling away would act as a lever on the bottom fastener.
Should I bother installing the second screw with the plastic drywall anchor? Would it add any notable structural integrity?

If the upper bracket mounting hole is higher than the drapery rod then I think it has a fair chance of holding the rod on its own. If the upper hole would be lower than the rod then I'll say there's just no good way of mounting the bracket with a single fastener.
You might consider installing a block of wood -- something like a rosette block -- as a backer for mounting the drapery. A piece of millwork/trim that extends the full height and/or width of the window could also provide for drapery mounting. This approach lets you fasten to the wall in a way and place that makes sense, then attach the drapery brackets with simple wood screws in exactly the spot where they need to be.

put the toggle bolt in the upper hole. the weight of the rod and curtain will tend to push the bottom of the bracket against the wall, so you can just use double sided tape there if there's no room for a lesser anchor.
Alternatively if you're using a gravity toggle you could pre-drill the foot and screw through the bottom hole into the toggle you installed in the top hole.
